# How to add scrollbar in JFrame with null layout?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollbar, null-layout-manager

I want to add a vertical scroll-bar on my `JFrame` with `null` layout.

Is it possible or not? please help!

Comment: yes no issue read official Oracle tutorial How to use ScrollPanes for worksing example, there is explained very well how, where, when .... JScrollPane works (JScrollbar is visible)

Comment: Start by using a layout manager...

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just set the `JScrollPane` as `ContentPane` for `JFrame` as it is described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html):

```
public class TabbedPaneTest {
    public static void main(String [] a) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        frame.setContentPane(pane);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In eclipse IDE you can use following code

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Test {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Test window = new Test();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Test() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel container = new JPanel();
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(container);
        container.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 250));
        container.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblHelloWorld = new JLabel("Hello World");
        lblHelloWorld.setBounds(10, 11, 101, 14);
        container.add(lblHelloWorld);

        frame.getContentPane().add(jsp);
    }
}
```